# Place button after text on same height

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a website for a client, and now I'm making an plan section with different versions of the product. The problem is that I don't know how to place all the buttons 40px below the column with the biggest text in a responsive way (without position:absolute, with hidden lines of text or with margins with line-heights etc.).

[Here an image from Photoshop (how I want it to be)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zBiR.png)

[And an image of how it actually is in my code (the problem)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYTAX.png)

I hope you guys understand what I'm trying to say and that you can help me! I think it's in this case not necessary to add my code, but if I'm wrong please tell me ;) I'm very curious how you guys fix this!

Frederick

Comment: and where's code that is not working?

Comment: you can use a css `min-height` for all items.

Comment: @jonju, I asked this more as a principle of how others are doing this. I use a standard column layout, so I thought everyone should know that, sorry. But next I will add my code.

Comment: @miglio, Thanks, i'm going to use the answer of asonnenshine in combination with the min-height solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [Zurb Foundation "Equalizer"](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/equalizer.html) for this sometimes, but there is another way to do it as shown below.

### HTML

Wrap the "features" text in a div container and the "ecommerce" elements in another div container.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-12 columns small-text-center">
    <h1>Uitvoeringen</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-3 columns">
    <div class="product">
      <div class="features">
        <h4>Finish:</h4>
        <p>Solid gold plating</p>
        <h4>Materials:</h4>
        <p>High grade steel
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="ecommerce">
        <button>Buy now</button>
        <p>Price per item</p>
        <p>Minimum order size 100 pieces</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-3 columns">
    <div class="product">
      <div class="features">
        <h4>Finish:</h4>
        <p>Solid gold plating</p>
        <h4>Materials:</h4>
        <p>High grade steel
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="ecommerce">
        <button>Buy now</button>
        <p>Price per item</p>
        <p>Minimum order size 100 pieces</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-3 columns">

    <div class="product">
      <div class="features">
        <h4>Finish:</h4>
        <p>Solid gold plating</p>
        <h4>Materials:</h4>
        <p>High grade steel</p>
        <h4>Finish:</h4>
        <p>Solid gold plating</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ecommerce">
        <button>Buy now</button>
        <p>Price per item</p>
        <p>Minimum order size 100 pieces</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-3 columns">
    <div class="product">
      <div class="features">
        <h4>Finish:</h4>
        <p>Solid gold plating with silver and platinum edging</p>
        <h4>Materials:</h4>
        <p>High grade steel
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="ecommerce">
        <button>Buy now</button>
        <p>Price per item</p>
        <p>Minimum order size 100 pieces</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

Then add a media query for larger screens (in this case, medium screens and up) with a fixed height for the "features" div container. This will allow the buttons to line up on large screens, and basic stacked blocks on small screens (responsive part):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
  .features {
    height: 260px;
  }
}
```

Here's [my CodePen example](http://codepen.io/asonnenshine/pen/xOrGyG)

Comment: Thanks! I think this is the best way to do this!

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this problem as the height automatically adjust itself.
To solve this problem put each content inside div tag and then adjust individual margin-bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a min-height in css around the top links.

```
    .column {
            width: 120px;
            display:block; 
            float: left; 
            margin:20px;
            /*the following is the value you need*/
            min-height:300px;}
```

See this link:
http://codepen.io/artchibald/pen/yJkYLW